# Not able to test meteor code which lives in /imports/client

Tags: testing, meteor, mocha.js

I test my meteor code which lives in `/imports/common` and `/imports/client` with test files in `/specs/common` and `/specs/server`. That works with `TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --driver-package dispatch:mocha --port 9000`.

When I try the same with code from `/imports/client` using test files in `/specs/client`, the paths to imported files from `/imports/client/...` cannot be resolved

So I put the test files in the same client directory where the code is:

```
/imports/client/code.js
/imports/client/code.test.js
```

The meteor docs say that `meteor test` eager loads all files with `.*test[s].*.js` including the `/imports` folder.

But when I run the test these tests won't be found:

`0 passing (0ms)`

I don't want to make UI tests or full app tests. I only want to test some functions I use in the client side code.

Comment: Is this an older Meteor project?

Comment: Yes, but it uses METEOR@2.4

Comment: So you did upgrade it from an older version to 2.4? I am asking, because the `dispatch:mocha` package is outdated and you should rather use [`meteortesting:mocha`](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-mocha) which is the same package but officially Meteor-Community maintained now.

Comment: You can move the functions to somewhere under `/imports/api` which can be tested.
Alternatively put your test files in `/imports/client` and they should load ok (they don't necessarily have to live in the same folder as the files they are testing, it's just a convention

Comment: @Mikkel test files in /imports/api cannot load the code, which should be tested from /imports/client . test files in /imports/client cannot be detected by mocha, I don't know why